# Removing branding from NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

Could any one help me to remove the "Nullsoft" label in NSIS installer? Please refer the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[BrandingText " "](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Removing_%27Nullsoft_Install_System_vX.XX%27_String_from_installer)

Comment: If you want to remove the line as well, you have to use GetDlgItem+ShowWindow in .onGuiInit

Comment: Is It legal to hide or change this name as you wish?

Comment: @Andark Yes but having the name there is good for users if they need to troubleshoot any problems they might have...

Answer (score 0):

to remove line from the bottom :

!insertmacro DestroyWindow  $HWNDPARENT 1045 # dimm remove line from bottom
[image]